# uicollectionview cells not showing on ipad in portrait mode

Tags: ipad, uicollectionview

my code/uicollectionview works on iphone 4 (portrait and landscape) and iPad landscape, but run same code on iPad in portrait mode, and screen remains blank.

i stumbled upon a fix, but do not understand the why.  posting the fix as answer.

Answer (score 0):

changing one line of code fixed the issue.  (why?)

from:

```
CGSize memberPhotoSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
```

to:

```
CGSize memberPhotoSize = CGSizeMake(75, 75);
```

now app shows the uicollectionview cells on ipad in portrait mode.